# Downgrade dependency version in gradle

Tags: build.gradle, dependency-management

I have excluded snakeyaml from all my dependencies, as i was unable to pin down which dependency has snakeyaml 1.33 in it's dependency tree.

However, the build is still failing, asking for a version of yaml that has been blocked by my org security policy.

I want to downgrade it to 1.29 version.

However, build fails searching for 1.33 even after using strict implementation like this:

```
implementation( group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml'){
        version{
            strictly '1.29'
        }
    }
```

1. What am i missing ?
2. Do i need to check dependency tree of plugins as well ? If yes, how can i do that? I used http://101coder.com/genTreeUI